# Is the extension of a perfect field by one of its algebraic closures always a Galois extension?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

Let $\overline{K}$ be an algebraic closure of a perfect field $K$. I have read that the *absolute Galois group* of a perfect field is simply $\text{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$. Yet if Galois groups are only defined for Galois extensions, then presumably $\text{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$ only makes sense if there is some a priori guarantee that $\overline{K}$ is a Galois extension of $K$.

Clearly it is an algebraic extension, but I cannot see how it would be guaranteed that the fixed field would be $K$ so that it is Galois.

Is $\overline{K}/K$ always Galois for perfect fields or am I missing something?

Comment: Take an element in $\overline K$ which is not in $K$. I think you can find an automorphism which moves it.

Comment: For a perfect field, any algebraic extension is separable, and an algebraic closure is normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\textbf{Galois = separable + normal}
$$
Note that $\overline{K}$ is always a normal extension of $K$. Thus, $\overline{K}$ is Galois over $K$ if and only if it is separable over $K$.
Hence, if $K$ is a perfect field, then indeed the algebraic closure of $K$ is a Galois extension of $K$.

$\textbf{Remark:}$ The notion of perfect field has many equivalent [definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_field). One of them says that a field is perfect if and only if any algebraic extension of it is separable.